# Penalty and knowing when I need to leave Dubai

Tags: visas

1. I came to Dubai last July 21 on a tourist visa for 30 days. I booked a return ticket on August 19, which is my last allowed day in Dubai. Is there a penalty when I arrive in the Philippines? Because I will be arriving in the Philippines on August 20.
2. When should I really leave Dubai? My last day is on August 19.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with when you arrive in Philippines. It is only about when you entered and left Dubai. So you're fine leaving on August 19 since it is within 30 days.

Comment: You could leave Dubai by boat and make your next entry into another country weeks later.  The time of your departure from Dubai is all that matters.

Answer (score 12):

The issue has nothing to do with when you arrive in Philippines. It is only about when you entered and left Dubai. So you're fine leaving on August 19 since it is within 30 days.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there will be any penalty based on ur current itinerary as you will be leaving Dubai, before the visa expires.

Visa is issued by UAE and you have to leave UAE before it expires.